# simplexml_import_dom loses text after last node

Tags: php, simplexml, domdocument

I have HTML coming from a WYSIWYG editor, so I have no control over the HTML that comes with it. And I need to parse to to create a PDF.

I create a DomDocument and load the HTML and pass it to simpleXML beacause it is easier to handle.
But every now and then I loose Text because it is set after the last HTML element.

```
// text to import
$text = "Text beginnning<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</strong>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur.<br \/><br \/><strong>Lorem ipsum 
        dolor sit amet, consetetur</strong><ul><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
        <\/li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur<\/li><li>Lorem ipsum 
        dolor sit amet, consetetur<\/li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
        <\/li><\/ul>Text after last node";

// Load text in dom and pass it to simplexml
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$dom->recover = true;
if ($dom) {
    $sxml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
    unset($dom);
    if ($sxml) {
        $this->parseHtmlContent($sxml->children());
    }
}
```

So "Text after last node" get's lost on the way and I don't know what to do?

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Why can't you use DOMDocument as it is? SimpleXML is not meant to handle HTML.

Comment: You can use `$dom->textContent` to extract only text from HTML

Comment: @silkfire because someone else build the whole parsing done in `this->parseHTMLContent` and I would have to rewrite the complete code. I just thought there might be an option I am missing to get text as child node.

Comment: @spankmaster79 How do you want to parse the HTML? Perhaps I can think up of a method for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML does not have any representation for text nodes, or indeed anything other than elements and attributes. You can get the complete string content for an element (or attribute) using a string cast (`(string)$simplexml_object`), but this is rarely what you would actually want in an HTML context - consider this simple piece of HTML:

```html
<p>some text with <em>an emphasised part</em> in the middle of it</p>
```

The "text content" of the `<p>` element, as given by SimpleXML, would be `"some text with  in the middle of it"` - the `"an emphasised part"` being instead the text content of the `<em>` element.

SimpleXML's text handling only really makes sense when an element has *either* child nodes *or* textual content, not a mixture of both. For XML as a data serialization, this makes sense - a hierarchical document with elements containing textual values is really easy to handle this way - but for a textual markup language, it is, as it were, "broken by design".

If you can guarantee that some part of the document will contain a particular structure of HTML (e.g. the `<ul>`/`<li>` sequence in your example) then you could use SimpleXML to parse just that part. The content either side of that `<ul>` could perhaps be recovered using the DOM and added back into your output.

Answer (score 0):

The text after the last node is on the same level as that node. The structure is:

```
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
      ["body"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) {
        ["p"]=>
        string(63) "Text beginnning
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur."
        ["ul"]=>
        object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
          ["li"]=>
          array(4) {
            [0]=>
            string(47) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
            "
            [1]=>
            string(38) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur"
            [2]=>
            string(46) "Lorem ipsum
            dolor sit amet, consetetur"
            [3]=>
            string(47) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
            "
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

So the body node contains other nodes and also a string. To get the string which is under the body node you have to call the `__toString` method:

```
$text = "Text beginnning<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</strong>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur.<br \/><br \/><strong>Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consetetur</strong><ul><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
        <\/li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur<\/li><li>Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consetetur<\/li><li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
        <\/li><\/ul>Text after last node";

$text = stripcslashes($text);

// Load text in dom and pass it to simplexml
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($text);
$dom->recover = true;

if ($dom) {
    $sxml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
    unset($dom);
    if ($sxml) {
        var_dump((string) $sxml->body);
    }
}
```

For further informations look at:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring
- http://de3.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php

Comment: `$sxml->asXML()` does have the text that is correct, but text is not counted as childnode as it seems by `$sxml->children()`. I'll strip the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the whole content is wrapped in a single containing element:

```
$dom->loadHTML('<div>' . $text . '</div>');
```